# How to fix "Thread 1: Exception: "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle" error in Xcode 11.4 when I do not have Main storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nsbundle

I know there are many questions here relating to this error but none of them quite fit my situation. I have made an Xcode project trying to create a star rating UIView with CocoaPods and Cosmos. I am following a tutorial. I was told in the beginning to delete the main storyboard and delete "main" as the main interface. So far I have installed two CocoaPods on my project through the terminal and I am now using a new workspace that CocoaPods created. Every time I run the simulator, my app crashes and I get the error mentioned above but I can't do anything because I have deleted the main storyboard. I have tried making a new one and re-coding and more but nothing works. In the tutorial, the guy ran the exact same code that I have and he just magically has a storyboard with stars on it that you can tap and change. I've done everything he has, how do I fix this?

[image: Here is my info.plist]

Comment: Would you be able to share your apps Info.plist... Also, is this app on a GitHub repository?

Comment: I've added the picture link for my info.plist and yes it is on a GitHub repository.

Comment: Someone below beat me to answering this but you need to change the value of the following key: UIMainStoryboardFile to your new storyboard.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm primarily new to Xcode and swift. Ho might I go about changing the value?

Comment: I think I'm just going to delete this project and start a new one because I've pretty much screwed this one. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

To delete Main.storyboard as the main interface you have to delete it from the Info.plist file too. Look for the property "Main storyboard file base name".

Comment: Thank you for answering! I linked my info.plist to my question. I do remember I did not delete the Main.storyboard from the info.plist but it is no there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete item in Application Scene Manifest. To keep your setting like the picture: [Correct Setting in info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnXRJ.png)